# Is there an easier way to convert milliseconds to HH.MM (decimal)?

Tags: t-sql

When converting milliseconds to HH.MM .....

```
SELECT empid, jobid, 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(Sum(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@duration))/(60*60)/1000)) 
 AS totaltime 
FROM completedshift 
GROUP BY employeeid
```

I don't feel like I should have to convert the sum of a convert.

Answer (score 0):

I can't voucher for the efficiency of it, but a quick google search landed me on the following [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa335d16-7d68-4dbf-85f6-08e40a2775e7/convert-millisecond-to-hhmmss-format?forum=transactsql).   You might be able to take the convert line and plug it into your code.

```
 declare @SomeMilliSecondsNumber bigint
 select @SomeMilliSecondsNumber =54013
 select convert(varchar,dateadd(ms,@SomeMilliSecondsNumber,0),114)
```

I can't access sqlfiddle at the moment, but will post when I get access.   I tried it in my DB at work with no issue.

**[View SQL Fiddle Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16450)**

Comment: I attempted using the above syntax and ended up with a conversion error of bigint to datetime. when I sum 159192000 and
3600000 together I should end up with 44.22

Comment: What version sql are you on?  Furthermore, I'm a bit confused to why you're converting to a decimal when you're looking for HH:MM. I added the sql fiddle code above, and it's only returning HH:MM as requested (the result of adding those two values together gave me 21:13:12:000); I'll research and see how you can take that number and convert back to a full datetime.

Comment: I am looking to take milliseconds to hh.mm not hh:mm. I need 8:30 to be 8.50

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue...

```
SELECT   employeeId, jobId, CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), totalTime)) / (60 * 60) / 1000) AS TotalTime
FROM     dbo.CompletedShift
GROUP BY employeeId, jobId
```

I had it right all along. I assumed that since I was getting 0.00 for most of my values that it wasn't working. Not realizing that most of my time entries were between 0 and 3 minutes. To get that precision I needed to do `DECIMAL(10,3)` for 0.038. In this case the precision wasn't needed and 0.00 is acceptable below 4 minutes.